# Could someone please explain this quote, preferably in beginner's language?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

On SQLAlchemy's documentation page the author starts with a philosophy,

> SQL databases behave less like object collections the more size and
>   performance start to matter; object collections behave less like
>   tables and rows the more abstraction starts to matter.

I'm scratching my head trying to understand the idea behind these two sentences, but failed. Could someone give an example illustrate the idea here? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are creating an application using an Object Oriented language and a SQL database, you are simultaneously working with two very different conceptual models for storing information:

- **The relational model** says how to store data in tables and rows and how to link elements through keys and joins.
- **The object model** establishes a way to store entities with attributes in memory (usually) and how to set links between them using pointers or references.

[image: Martin Fowler's depiction of translating information between the relational and object models]

So, let's say that you have an User entity that is linked to addresses and other users in your application. Those entities will need to be stored in the form several tables in the database (users table, addresses table and a many to many table for associating users to users, for instance). At the same time, if your code uses object oriented constructs, users and addresses will exist in memory in the form of objects with references between them, pointing to objects of the same or different kind.

The thing is, moving information between those two different worlds is much much more difficult than it looks at first:

- You might associate one object with one row in a table, but that is not always possible and sometimes a single object must be associated to multiple rows in different tables.
- Inheritance and polymorphic behavior are particularly difficult to map to a relational model.
- Traversing objects and querying the database are vastly different actions.
- Performance factors to take into account in an object model and a relational model are completely different.

And those are just a few examples. ORMs such as SQLAlchemy are essentially *translators* that convert information from one world into the other and back.

What I think that **Mike Bayer** was trying to convey is: the more you adapt your entity information to the object model (lots of inheritance, polymorphism, traversal of objects, ...), the farther it will resemble the natural structure in a relational model and the more performance concessions you will be making. And the other way around: the more you design your tables to perform well and be optimized for your queries, the less they will adapt to a natural structure of objects.

Martin Fowler has a nice write-up about the need of this translation in this article: [ORM Hate](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/OrmHate.html) (from which I took the above image).

**Edit: further clarification on the abstraction vs performance issue**

At the end, I think that the bottom line of that SQLAlchemy presentation text is: many ORMs hide the relational side of the relational-object oriented translation to make things easier. With them you only have to worry about the object oriented side, and the library is in charge of taking away the *burden* of dealing with the database. You get persistence for your objects without having to deal with SQL. However, they incur in a performance penalty in doing so, because the details of working with the database are abstracted away and you have no control over them. And those details are *essential* when you have to optimize performance. SQLAlchemy takes the opposite approach. It hides nothign of the relational side, you are in control of how SQL is generated and when and when not use joins, subqueries and other SQL constructs. That makes it a much more complex library to learn, but at the same time you are in control of the whole relational-object oriented translation process.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So in the second sentence the word "abstraction" refers to object-oriented thinking?  Did I get it right? I'm lost because everything in computer science boils down to abstraction.

Comment: I think a study group for Mike's bible is much in need for beginners:)

Comment: Yes, I think "abstraction" refers there to modeling your solution using object oriented concepts. I have edited the post to add a clarification about that. I have used SQLAlchemy for some years now and it is a amazing library. I totally agree with its design principles. It is a very hard one to learn too, especially for a beginner, but don't give up! Totally worth it :)